# Bootstrap Popover won't show: Error please use show on visible elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, dom

I've created a popover that launches when you click on the specified area with the corresponding `data-toggle`, it's working perfectly in Chrome but in Firefox I keep getting the error:

> Error: Please use show on visible elements
>   show, _enter, toggle, _setListeners, dispatch, handle

The error resides in the  `bootstrap.min.js` file that is used in my project.

Now I know that it has probably something to do with adding `('show')`after the `.popover` part, but I can't get it to work. My popover function:

```js
 // popover initialization - on click
        $('[data-toggle="zero-1"]').popover({
          html: true,
          trigger: 'click',
          placement: 'bottom',

          // main function when popover fires
          content: function engine() {
           
            // execute the actions of the lawmaker() first, then the ruler()
            return lawmaker(this,this,this) + ruler((($(this).data('xray'))),(($(this).data('yray'))));

            // insert image and close button in popover
            function lawmaker(i1,a1, b1,) {

               // get the data-image str value
               var mig = $(i1).data('img');
               // console.log(mig);

               // return the visuals and close button for the popover
               return '<img src="' + mig + '" /> <button id="close-popover" data-toggle="clickover" class="btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right" onclick="$(\'.popover\').remove();">Close please!</button>'; 
         }
          }
        });
```

```css
    
.popover {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(258px, 63px, 0px);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    will-change: transform;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<map>
<area class="grz" data-toggle="zero-1" data-xray="105" data-yray="70" shape="rect" coords="80,60,130,80" href="javascript://" data-img="img/zero/zero-2.png" title="Zero">
</map>
```

Any thoughts in solving this problem? :)

Comment: Could you provide more example code? HTML/CSS? It's difficult to tell, but it sounds like it could be an issue with Browser based styling.

Comment: @zfrisch Yes, added the context!

Comment: The error I see here tells me popperjs hasn't been added. You could use the CDN to add that if you already haven't. Maybe a codepen showing your HTML would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I tried to initialize tooltip via javascript, tooltip din't work, yet there was no error. I got the same error as you've quoted in the question when I used `$(element).tooltip().tooltip('show')`.

Here is link to possible reason why that happens https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24918.

I ended up just putting html attributes on tooltip element to get it working

```html
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="my tootltip content">help</span>
```